# Как отработать код только один раз при выполнении условий

Tags: javascript, функции, анимация

В тот момент, когда координаты красного и синего блока совпадают, срабатывает console.log(), но не знаю, как сделать, чтобы он срабатывал один раз во время одного прикосновения, а не много раз, как происходит.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('block1');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const canvasB = document.getElementById('block2');
    let ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d');

    let redM = {
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
    };

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(redM.x, redM.y, redM.width, redM.height);

    let blueM = {
        x: 100,
        y: 40,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        speed: 5,
    };

    requestAnimationFrame(tick);

    function tick() {
        ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, canvasB.width, canvasB.height);
        ctxB.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctxB.fillRect(blueM.x, blueM.y, blueM.width, blueM.height);
        blueM.x += blueM.speed;
        if (blueM.x + blueM.width > canvasB.width) {
            blueM.speed = -blueM.speed;
            blueM.x = canvasB.width - blueM.width;
        }
        if (blueM.x < 0) {
            blueM.speed = -blueM.speed;
            blueM.x = 0;
        }

        if ((redM.x > blueM.x && redM.x < blueM.x + blueM.width) && (redM.y > blueM.y && redM.y < blueM.y + blueM.height)) {
            console.log('hi');
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
<canvas id="block1" width="600" height="300" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
<canvas id="block2" width="600" height="300" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант, поставьте условие: if (count == 0) { console.log(...) count++}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например при помощи флага:

```js
let collision = false; // признак коллизии
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let ctxB = canvasB.getContext('2d');
let redM = {x: 50, y: 50,width: 50, height: 50};
let blueM = {x: 100, y: 40,width: 100, height: 100,speed: 5};

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(redM.x, redM.y, redM.width, redM.height);
requestAnimationFrame(tick);

function tick() {
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, canvasB.width, canvasB.height);
  ctxB.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctxB.fillRect(blueM.x, blueM.y, blueM.width, blueM.height);
  blueM.x += blueM.speed;
  if (blueM.x + blueM.width > canvasB.width) {
    blueM.speed = -blueM.speed;
    blueM.x = canvasB.width - blueM.width;
  }
  if (blueM.x < 0) {
    blueM.speed = -blueM.speed;
    blueM.x = 0;
  }

  if ((redM.x > blueM.x && redM.x < blueM.x + blueM.width) && 
      (redM.y > blueM.y && redM.y < blueM.y + blueM.height)) {
      
    if (!collision) // если блоки в прошлом кадре не пересекались
      console.log('hi');
      
    collision = true;
  } else {
    collision = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvasB" width="600" height="300" style="position: absolute"></canvas>
</div>
```